# custom attribute (data-) in HTML not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an select bar with a few options where I am trying to sort some things and I am also trying to implement, that if you click the option again then it will switch to ascending or descending order.

I have this HTML elements:

```html
<select name="theme" id="sortSelect">
  <option> -
  </option>
  <option value="firstName" data-sort-direction="asc">First Name
  </option>
  <option value="lastName" data-sort-direction="asc">Last Name
  </option>
  <option value="house" data-sort-direction="asc">House
  </option>
</select>
```

I get the value in JavaScript by using this keyword, I have added an event listener to listen for a 'change' and that leads to a function and inside that function I'm getting the value like this: `const selectedValue = this.value;`
that works totally fine but when I try to get the `data-sort-direction='asc'` in JavaScript like this: `let sortDirection = this.dataset.sortDirection;` then it returns undefined. What am I doing wrong here? help would be much appreciated!

edit: these are the 2 functions that I'm using:

```
function getSortedValues() {
  const selectedValue = this.value;
  let sortDirection = this.dataset.sortDirection;
  if (sortDirection === 'asc') {
    this.dataset.sortDirection = 'desc';
  } else {
    this.dataset.sortDirection = 'asc';
  }
  console.log(sortDirection);
  getSortedStudent(selectedValue, sortDirection);
}

function getSortedStudent(pressedValue, sortDirection) {
  let sortedStudents = [];

  let direction = 1;
  if (sortDirection === 'desc') {
    direction = -1;
  } else {
    sortDirection = 1;
  }

  sortedStudents = allStudents.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[pressedValue] < b[pressedValue]) {
      return -1 * direction;
    } else {
      return 1 * direction;
    }
  });
  displayList(sortedStudents);
}
```

Comment: can you edit your post with your js function?

Comment: i editted it @ArnaudV

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but some code review: Prefixing a function with the word `get` usually implies that it returns a value without modifying anything. Your `get` functions actually perform a change on the page when called and don't return anything, which is rather counter-intuitive. Also, all your variables could be constants. `const direction = (sortDirection === 'desc') ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Thanks for comment @Domino, I am still a beginner so I am trying to write code that is as much understandable and readable as possible for me. I had no idea you could do that and I haven't seen this kind of code before either.

Comment: @Domino But thinking about it, now the code works and it sorts between  ascended and descended but only if i first choose one option and then another option. So i cannot double click to change it. Should i use another type of  event listener instead of change? or is it the fault of the select that works like this and you cant double click? the event listener 'click' is not working since it changes the values when the dropdown with the options appears and not when i click on the option itself. hmmm any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.dataset` is the `data` attributes of the `<select>`, not the `<option>`. You can get that via:

```
let sortDirection = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.sortDirection;
```

Note, this may still be `undefined`, as your initial option doesn't have a `data-sort-direction` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [@Tim Lewis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63906402/7314155), the select value attribute changes, but nothing else from `<option>` is carried over. There are a lot of ways to find the selected item with radios, checkbox, or dropdowns, but my preferred method is the `:checked` pseudo selector. Here's an example.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#sortSelect')
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var selectedOption = document.querySelector('option:checked')
  console.log(this.value, selectedOption.dataset);
})
```

```html
<select name="theme" id="sortSelect">
  <option> -
  </option>
  <option value="firstName" data-sort-direction="asc">First Name
  </option>
  <option value="lastName" data-sort-direction="asc">Last Name
  </option>
  <option value="house" data-sort-direction="asc">House
  </option>
</select>
```